# EmberError could not find template or view

Tags: ember.js

We have an EmberJS application and the below runtime error occurs around startup time each time I attempt to run the app.  This is a problem that is only window specific.  Mac works perfectly fine.    I believe vendor.js contains many of our 3rd party libraries our app depends upon.  Where can I start to debug this problem?  One suggested a potential problem maybe with web pack?  Is this the right place to start? I'm new here to this project and as far as I know no one at the company has ever developed using a windows environment.  I suspect there are many mac specific items that are in place.  Just not exactly sure where to begin with this.  Any hints would be great.   Thanks

```
 EmberError description : undefined fileName : undefined lineNumber :
 undefined message : "Assertion Failed: Could not find "svg.iconCharts" template or view." name : "Error" number : undefined stack : 
"Error: Assertion Failed: Could not find "svg.iconCharts" template or view.↵  
 at new EmberError (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:39962:23)↵    at
 Object.Ember.assert (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:29576:15)↵    at
 Class.render (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:51100:17)↵    at
 Class.renderTemplate (https://localhost:3000/main.js:63561:18)↵    at
 apply (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:45385:27)↵    at
 Class.superWrapper [as renderTemplate]
 (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:44956:15)↵    at Class.setup
 (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:50366:16)↵    at applyHook
 (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:72695:30)↵    at callHook
 (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:72689:14)↵    at
 handlerEnteredOrUpdated (https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:71449:7)"
    __proto__ : Error
    reportError @   errors.js:6
    error   @   base.js:71
    triggerEvent    @   ember.debug.js:26351
    trigger @   ember.debug.js:46873
    trigger @   ember.debug.js:46718
    finalizeTransition  @   ember.debug.js:45907
    (anonymous) @   ember.debug.js:45309
    tryCatch    @   ember.debug.js:47307
    invokeCallback  @   ember.debug.js:47319
    publish @   ember.debug.js:47290
    (anonymous) @   ember.debug.js:29435
    invoke  @   ember.debug.js:679
    flush   @   ember.debug.js:749
    end @   ember.debug.js:135
    (anonymous) @   ember.debug.js:521
    setTimeout (async)      
    createAutorun   @   ember.debug.js:519
    defer   @   ember.debug.js:219
    run.schedule    @   ember.debug.js:18411
    raf @   fastdom.js:67
    scheduleFlush   @   fastdom.js:197
    measure @   fastdom.js:98
    (anonymous) @   eq.js:376
    load (async)        
    addEvent    @   eq.js:38
    (anonymous) @   eq.js:375
    fn  @   bootstrap:98
    ./app/scripts/dependencies.js   @   wizard.js:204
    __webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:721
    fn  @   bootstrap:98
    ./app/scripts/app.js    @   ajax.js:90
    __webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:721
    fn  @   bootstrap:98
    1   @   main.js:123381
    __webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:721
    ./app/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot.module.exports    @   bootstrap:788
    (anonymous) @   bootstrap:788
```

Comment: Does this happen right after running `ember s` or when you open page in browser? If it happens during building and happens under windows only, it's better to get a mac or install Ubuntu as second OS. You may also try to use Ubuntu in Virtualbox/VMware, if you strictly against second OS idea. The reason for this is because it seems not a lot of frontend developers use Windows, which leads to poor support from different tools.

Comment: Thanks Gennady.  This problem happens when I open the page in the browser.  I'm in the process of getting a mac.  But in the meantime I'm stuck with my personal laptop for now which unfortunately is windows.

Comment: Did your coworkers provide you with clear build instructions? Maybe you just missing some important step

Comment: Yes build instructions are very clear.  They didn't know what was happening when I showed them this issue.  None of them use windows so it looks like no one ever tested developing on it.

Comment: This may be an issue not with build but with specific browser and may affect users of your app. If you have that app deployed somewhere on test or production server, you should test if it works on your laptop. In this way you will know if app is broken for Windows users or just building process is broken on Windows

Comment: Works perfectly fine when I run the production build on my windows chrome/firefox.  Looks like it may something with the build process.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is it’s a path issue in development mode for one of your app dependencies. If you search for the `svg.iconCharts` string you may find the addon that is having issues